# Orders are not being associated with customers for register and checkout option

Tags: checkout, orders, customer, customer-account, register

The orders are saving to the sales grid correctly. Sales > Orders
The problem is when i look for the order under Magento Admin->Customers->Manage Customers->[CUSTOMER]->Orders; there is nothing.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Nothing really to report in the system.log or exception.log, here is both below.

```
2018-02-02T08:02:44+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: compressor  in /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/community/Swarming/Pagespeed/Model/Observer/ConfigData.php on line 70
2018-02-02T08:02:44+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: compressor  in /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/community/Swarming/Pagespeed/Model/Observer/ConfigData.php on line 72
2018-02-02T08:02:44+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: enable_less  in /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/community/Swarming/Pagespeed/Model/Observer/ConfigData.php on line 83
2018-02-02T08:02:44+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: less_js  in /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/community/Swarming/Pagespeed/Model/Observer/ConfigData.php on line 89
2018-02-02T08:02:44+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: less_js_watch  in /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/community/Swarming/Pagespeed/Model/Observer/ConfigData.php on line 89
2018-02-02T20:40:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Max retry:6 retry power:2
2018-02-02T21:26:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): Max retry:6 retry power:2
2018-02-02T21:41:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): Max retry:6 retry power:2
2018-02-05T21:04:56+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Declaration of Uni_Fileuploader_Block_Adminhtml_Fileuploader_Edit_Tab_Productfile::getRowUrl() should be compatible with Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::getRowUrl($item)  in /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/community/Uni/Fileuploader/Block/Adminhtml/Fileuploader/Edit/Tab/Productfile.php on line 9
2018-02-06T15:31:11+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Declaration of Uni_Fileuploader_Block_Adminhtml_Fileuploader_Edit_Tab_Productfile::getRowUrl() should be compatible with Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::getRowUrl($item)  in /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/community/Uni/Fileuploader/Block/Adminhtml/Fileuploader/Edit/Tab/Productfile.php on line 9
```

exception.log

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'API Request Failed: 404 returned.' in /home/_magento/master/html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/local/Swarming/Erp/Model/Abstract/Connector.php(152): Mage::throwException('API Request Fai...')
#1 /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/local/Swarming/Erp/Model/Abstract/Connector.php(180): Swarming_Erp_Model_Abstract_Connector->post(true)
#2 /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/local/Swarming/Erp/Model/Observer.php(277): Swarming_Erp_Model_Abstract_Connector->postData(Array)
#3 [internal function]: Swarming_Erp_Model_Observer->syncSubmissionQueue(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#4 /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(196): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(582): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
#6 /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
#7 /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /home/_magento/master/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /home/_magento/master/html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#10 /home/_magento/master/html/shell/scheduler.php(377): Mage::dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#11 /home/_magento/master/html/shell/scheduler.php(37): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->cronAction()
#12 /home/_magento/master/html/shell/scheduler.php(403): Aoe_Scheduler_Shell_Scheduler->run()
#13 {main}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the customers are not guest?

Comment: @RintoGeorge it's actually when they hit the register and checkout button. See screenshot attached.